# Making Contour Plot in R More Efficient

Tags: r, plot

I need some help rewriting my code. I have some code that I wrote in `R` for a contour plot that I want. The code works, however, it is very inefficient in that it has to plot thousands of points to get exactly what I want (the grey area), and so I would like to see if there is a simpler way to do what my code is doing.

I basically want to plot the function

```
f = x1 + x2
```

subject to the following constraint functions

```
c1 = 3/2 - x1 - 2x2 - 1/2*sin(2*pi(x1^2 - 2x2)) < 0

c2 = x1^2+x2^2-3/2 < 0
```

And so where c1 and c2 are both greater than zero, I would like to grey out those areas, and only show the function f where c1 and c2 are less than 0. And the domain of x1 and x2 are between 0 and 1.

Here is my current R code:

```
x1 = seq(0,1,.001) 
x2 = seq(0,1,.001)

f = function(x1,x2){   
ans = x1 + x2   
return(ans) }


h = function(x1,x2){   
ans1 = 1.5-x1-2*x2-.5*sin(2*pi*(x1^2-2*x2))   
ans2 = x1^2+x2^2-1.5   
ans1 = sapply(ans1,function(x){max(x,0)})   
ans2 = sapply(ans2,function(x){max(x,0)})   
ans = ans1 + ans2   
return(ans) }

z = outer(x1,x2,f) 
w = outer(x1,x2,h)

image(x1,x2,z,xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2])) 
contour(x1,x2,z,add=TRUE)

X = cbind(expand.grid(x1,x2),c(w)) 
points(X[X[,3]!=0,1],X[X[,3]!=0,2],pch=19,col="lightgrey")
```

Comment: Use `pmax` instead of `max`.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for the suggestion. But I guess I meant I want something more efficient with regards to the number of points I have to use. So for example, instead of using points to make the grey area, is there an equivalent way to do it with say the polygon command?

Comment: Have you tried the `filled.contour` function instead of `contour`?

Comment: @user2554330 No i haven't. Could you give me an example with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `.filled.contour`, the working function behind `filled.contour`.  (The full `filled.contour` makes it hard to annotate your plot.)  For example

```
x1 = seq(0,1,.001) 
x2 = seq(0,1,.001)

f = function(x1,x2){   
  ans = x1 + x2   
  return(ans) }


h = function(x1,x2){   
  ans1 = 1.5-x1-2*x2-.5*sin(2*pi*(x1^2-2*x2))   
  ans2 = x1^2+x2^2-1.5   
  ans1 = pmax(ans1,0)   
  ans2 = pmax(ans2,0)  
  ans = ans1 + ans2   
  return(ans) }

z = outer(x1,x2,f) 
w = outer(x1,x2,h)

# Set up the plot, .filled.contour doesn't do that
plot(x1, x2, type="n", xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]))

# Set a gray background
rect(min(x1), min(x2), max(x1), max(x2), col = "gray")

# Make parts transparent
z[ w != 0 ] <- NA

# Choose the contour levels
levels <- pretty(z)

# Plot them
.filled.contour(x1,x2,z,levels, 
               hcl.colors(length(levels)-1, "ylOrRd", rev = TRUE)) 

# If your device does antialiasing, plot the filled contours twice to avoid 
# ugly effects

.filled.contour(x1,x2,z,levels, 
               hcl.colors(length(levels)-1, "ylOrRd", rev = TRUE)) 

contour(x1,x2,z, levels = levels, add=TRUE)
```

This gives me

[image: screenshot]